Is there a way to make a BTC wallet address public but hide how many BTC it contains?
So for example if you want to publicise a BTC wallet address so as to accept donations for a project, is there a way to hide the amount that has been received in donations so far?

Normally an address is an encoding of a specific output script, so all transactions using that address are linkable by that script. However, recently a standard has been developed called Silent Payments that uses addresses whose transactions aren't linked together because the address is used to derive a unique output script for each transaction.

Technically Bitcoin address does not contain any bitcoins, individual transaction outputs do. These outputs can be linked together if same address is used multiple times. Best is to avoid address reuse. Any decent wallet can generate billions of addresses. Silent payments is nice idea, but they aren't here yet, you should look at accepting donations by hosting some payment processor, for example, BTCPay Server or SatSale, that will show new address every time donation page is opened.
